# QGIS Update Column

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have a CSV file which I would like to join to a TAB file.

The TAB file has the table structure shown below. The column PLAN_NO is the unique reference in this table.

[image]

The CSV file has the table structure shown below. The column TILE_REF is the unique reference in this table.

[image]

When the two columns PLAN_NO and TILE_Ref match I'd like to update the column EA_1M_DSM in the TAB file with the letter 'Y'.

How do you do this in QGIS?

Comment: Are you asking for the concept/workflow, or how you write "Y" in the new column?

Comment: can you illustrate the tables and what do you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the field calculator. First, do the join, then an expression like this into the 'EXISTS' field should work:

```
CASE
WHEN "TILE_REF" = "PLAN_NO" THEN 'Y'
ELSE ''
END
```